# providing a similarly named static and non-static method in C#

Tags: c#

I apologize if this is a repeat. But I am wondering if it is wise in some situations to provide a method that has both a static and non-static version. (Non-static version provided through Extension.) I just created such a thing, but I'm wondering if I should have in the first place.

Take the following as an example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict {get; private set;}

    public MyClass(Dictionary<string, string> dict) { this.Dict = dict; }

    public static DataTable CreateTable(MyClass data)
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        foreach (string column in data.Dict.Keys)
        {
            result.Columns.Add(column, typeof(string));
        }  
        DataRow dr = result.NewRow();
        foreach (string column in data.Dict.Keys)
        {
            dr[column] = data.Dict[column];
        } 
        return result;
    }  
}

public static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static DataTable CreateTable(this MyClass data)
    {
        return MyClass.CreateTable(data);
    }
}
```

Doing this will allow person to use 
`MyClass.CreateTable(new MyClass(a dictionary object));` 
or

```
List<MyClass> cs = new List<MyClass>();
Dictionary<string,string> d;
MyClass c;

d = new Dictionary<string,string>() {{"First Name", "John"}, {"Last Name", "Doe"}, {"ID", "123-1234-123"}};
c = new MyClass(d);
cs.Add(c);

d = new Dictionary<string,string>() {{"First Name", "Jack"}, {"Last Name", "Mare"}, {"ID", "123-1234-124"}};
c = new MyClass(d);
cs.Add(c);

d = new Dictionary<string,string>() {{"First Name", "Jill"}, {"Last Name", "Hen"}, {"ID", "123-1234-126"}};
c = new MyClass(d);
cs.Add(c);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (MyClass ct in cs)
{
    dt.Merge(ct.CreateDataTable(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
}
```

Obviously, my application of the class is slightly more complicated than this. Also, even though I have this set up as a Dictionary -> DataTable conversion, I suppose one could do a DataTable -> Dictionary conversion.  That's not the point of the question, though.

Comment: Technically you have a static method and an extension method.  Yes I could see where they could be confusing.

Comment: Not a good decision. Are you going to duplicate all of your classes methods? No, so be consistent :)  
+ Dont create extension methods for your classes that you own

Comment: There's not a technically right or wrong answer; voting to close an opinion-based.

Comment: Agree with @Tournash - extension methods are to extend classes that _you don't own_.  If you want it to look like an instance method then _make it an instance method_.

Comment: Why is allowing that an advantage and not a disadvantage? Do you provide two different APIs for other features?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve exactly with that class, who will consume it and etc.. but technically I see no problem with the fact that you have a static method and an instance method of the same name. I would suggest that having an extension method to a class of your own is not a good practice as Tourmash already suggested. and as D Stanley noted - this tend to be opinion based discussion and therefore I will vote to close it as well - but u do get +1 since it is an interesting question :)

Comment: Thank you, all. Feel free to close. It is more of an opinion discussion, isn't it.  You addressed my concern, though. Better to be consistent, no duplicating work.  And, I suppose, I can leave it static as it is not modifying anything in this object. (But I will read up on that topic as Microsoft (and others) have good explanations on that.)

Comment: FYI: I find it interesting that this works.

Comment: @Machtyn you can also make it non-static - then it would be called just like the extension method would.  There's no reason to make it static that I can see.